# Why would you use a BitSet in java as opposed to an array of booleans (in Java)?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitset

Other than the difference in methods available, why would someone use a BitSet as opposed to an array of booleans? Is performance better for some operations?

Comment: You could perform bit-level operations on the entire set, for example. Otherwise, there's no difference in memory or anything like that. But it's a little faster to `&` or `|` a bitset than loop over an array of booleans and do the same thing.

Comment: @Kon: `there's no difference in memory`. Not true - a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) uses an array of `long[]` to store the bits.  It is much more compact that an array of booleans.

Comment: The `BitSet` implementation in Oracle's JDK is implemented in a way that is much more memory efficient than an array of booleans, using 1 bit per "bit" where an array of booleans will use 1 byte per "bit".

Comment: @GregKopff Thanks for the information, I did not know that. Never looked at the implementation, just assumed the simplest case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would do it to save space: a `boolean` occupies a whole byte, so an array of `N` `boolean`s would occupy eight times the space of a `BitSet` with the equivalent number of entries.

Execution speed is another closely related concern: you can produce a union or an intersection of several `BitSet` objects faster, because these operations can be performed by CPU as bitwise ANDs and ORs on 32 bits at a time.

Comment: OTOH, some bitwise operations (like getting a single bit) will be slightly slower than an array of Booleans.

Comment: @user949300 Even for those, it _could_ be that in some circumstances those operations will be faster, if the increased data locality keeps more of the bits in the CPU cache. I'm not sure if that'd be enough to offset the extra instructions, but it might be.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the space savings noted by @dasblinkenlight, a BitSet has the advantage that it will grow as needed.  If you do not know beforehand how many bits will be needed, or the high numbered bits are sparse and rarely used, (e.g. you are detecting which Unicode characters are present in a document and you want to allow for the unusual "foreign" ones > 128 but you know that they will be rare) a BitSet will save even more memory.